# Android Animation: How to set an ImageView's layout coordinates to the translated ImagiveView after Translational Annimation

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I have a button defined in my XML layout, when it is clicked it calls a function that is supposed to translate the ImageView man 100 pixals to the right, it moves the image to the right but when i click the button a second time it resets the image to its starting position and repeats the same animation across the same path. (i have android:fillAfter="true" in my xml) I tried adding the following line inside the onAnimationEnd -

```
 @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

                man.layout(xCurrentPos + 100, yCurrentPos, xCurrentPos+ (man.getWidth()) + 100, yCurrentPos + man.getHeight());

            }
```

however when the animation finishes the ImageView glitches a bit to the left of where the ImageView stopped its animation (it hops backwards a bit) i tried playing with xCurrentPos + 100 parameters example changing it to xCurrentPos + 70 to get it to stop glitching but nothing worked, also i tried putting

```
man.layout(man.getLeft(), man.getTop(), man.getRight(), man.getBottom());
```

in the onAnimationEnd however it just reset the image to its orginal postion

Here is my code,

```
package com.junglejackapps.theman;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button bup, bdown, bleft, bright;
    int xCurrentPos;
    int yCurrentPos;

        ImageView man;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        bup = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
        bdown = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
        bleft = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
        bright = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
        man = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.man); 

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick_function_up (View v) {

    }

    public void onClick_function_right (View v) {

        xCurrentPos = man.getLeft(); 
        yCurrentPos = man.getTop(); 

        Animation anim= new TranslateAnimation(xCurrentPos, xCurrentPos+100, yCurrentPos, yCurrentPos); 
        anim.setDuration(2500); 
        anim.setFillAfter(true); 
        anim.setFillEnabled(true); 
        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {

                man.layout(xCurrentPos + 100, yCurrentPos, xCurrentPos+ (man.getWidth()) + 100, yCurrentPos + man.getHeight());

            }
        });
        man.startAnimation(anim);

    }

    public void onClick_function_down (View v) {

    }

    public void onClick_function_left (View v) {

    }


}
```

and my XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/man"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/arrow"
        android:src="@drawable/man"

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="" 
        android:onClick="onClick_function_up" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:text="" 
        android:onClick="onClick_function_up_down"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
        android:text="" 
        android:onClick="onClick_function_right"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text=""
        android:onClick="onClick_function_left" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using deltas in the animation, and set the margins at the end.

Here's an example:

```
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, amountToMoveRight, amountToMoveDown);
        anim.setDuration(2500);

        anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
            {
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
                params.topMargin += amountToMoveDown;
                params.leftMargin += amountToMoveRight;
                view.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        });

        view.startAnimation(anim);
```

Make sure `fillAfter` is set to `false` in this scenario.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Gil Moshayof! The people shall cry! Master teacher of the codes! this has done more than just help fine sir, excellence! thank you!